# SWT: how to compute correct size of wrapped text

Tags: java, layout, swt, word-wrap

I have a Label component which can contain a very long text. Label support wrapping:

```
Label label = new Label( composite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.LEFT );
```

So when I decrease the width of the parent Composite - just resize it with mouse - the text is wrapped correctly, but the height of the parent Composite is not changed so some part of my Label get hidden.

[image]

I tried to add a resize listener to parent composite:

```
expandBar.addListener( SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent( Event e ) {
    Point p = label.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT ) // compute size of the text
    int h = p.y; // ! THIS value doesn't change 
                      // despite text in label became wrapped
    // now set expandBar current item's height = h;
  }
} );
```

Is there a way to compute the height of the component with regards to wrapping?
If no, are there SWT components/layouts which change its size dynamically if the child is getting wrapped?

Comment: To workaround this issue we can use ScrollableComposite as a parent comtainer. See this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123/prevent-swt-scrolledcomposite-from-eating-part-of-its-children