# Automatically set jface Dialog minimum size: do not let widgets disappear

Tags: dialog, jface, resizable, minimum-size

I would like to make sure that no widget in a `jface` `Dialog` is ever disappearing.

Scrollability would be an easy solution, but I would prefer a resizable window that is always at least as large as to display all contents. Do you know of any setting to enable this functionality?

Comment: [Prevent SWT scrolledComposite from eating part of it's children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123/prevent-swt-scrolledcomposite-from-eating-part-of-its-children)

Comment: You can set size of Dialog's shell according to result of computeSize for the content control.